# implementing an email and confirmation email function with angular

Tags: angular, email, angular7, email-validation

i'am trying to implement a function to check email and confirmation email with angular, when i type a different confirmation email, my function work and i get an error , now when i try to correct the email and make it same as the confirmation email i still get the error even if the two emails are same

the body of the function:

```
  static checkEmails(group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
    const email = group.controls.email.value;
    const confirmEmail = group.controls.confirmEmail.value;

    const responseKo = { NOT_SAME: true };
    const responseOk = null;

    let identical = false;
    if (email.toLowerCase() === confirmEmail.toLowerCase()) {
      identical = true;
    } else {
      group.controls.confirmEmail.setErrors(responseKo);
    }

    return identical ? responseOk : responseKo;
  }
```

Comment: hope this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-confirmation-custom-validator) could help you!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a form validator for that ?

```js
const emailChecker = (form: FormGroup) => {
  const email = form.get('email').value;
  const confirm = form.get('confirm').value;

  return email === confirm ? null : { emailConfirm: 'Email confirm mismatch' };
};

// ...

this.form = this.builder.group({ ... });
this.form.setValidators([emailChecker]);
```

Comment: thank you for the response
could you be more specific?

Comment: Well I thought my answer was ... What don't you understand ?

Comment: well, it doesn't work for me , still had the same issue

Comment: It's easy to say that. Please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue you have, it will be clearer and will help me explain you the issue on your code.

Comment: i updated the question , hope that it will be clear for you

Comment: I have already provided the answer to your question, you said you don't understand it. So please, provide a [mcve] of your issue, so that I can explain it to you !

Comment: thank you for the answer :) but it doesn't work for me , i understood what you had wrote

Comment: and I understood it didn't work for you, that's why I'm askinf for a [mcve], to explain to you how it works !!!